# How to access non-pivot data in a pivot measure in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Excel - I have built a pivot table showing the number of projected transactions.  I have changed my screenshot to make it a little easier to understand.  I have total projected vehicle sales in a pivot table.  I have another section of data which shows how many reps  we have for each vehicle type.  I have set up a relationship between these 2 objects. I want to create a measure (which I can then add to the pivot table) which divides the various numbers by the rep count... In effect I want each number in the cars section divided by 62, each number in the Trucks section divided by 39, and each number in the Motorcycles section divided by 34.

The code I am using is

```
=[Distinct Count of Opportunities] / LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[Reps], Table1[Vehicle Type]], [Vehicle Type])
```

To try to simplify, I am just using the 2nd part of the calculation...

```
=LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[Reps], Table1[Vehicle Type]], [Vehicle Type])
```

I am getting the error: The value for Vehicle Type cannot be determined. Either Vehicle Type doesn't exist or there is no current row for a column named 'Vehicle Type'.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Would it help to join the 2 tables first and use the result as the base for the pivot action?  Within the pivot table it is possible to defined calculated fields as well.

Comment: @Anonymous - I was able to join first, but that is really not the way I want to go.  Was hoping for something else.  I cannot use calculated fields, since the pivot is based on a table w/ Data model, which is needed in order to do a distinct count.

Comment: Yes, the statement of calculated fields was related to that you can join the tables. You can try with UNIQUE and FILTER and some aggregation to create the table without using pivot (it is not exactly the same, but maybe with enough data to do your lookup)

Comment: (Actually, depending on the effort you want to spend, e.g. with TRANSPOSE of the month column you could make the same as the pivot)

Comment: Probably, you already know it: there is also this function to extract data from pivot tables: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/getpivotdata-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f